# Docusign integration with IBM FileNet

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi, filenet-p8

We are trying to integrate asp.net site front-end having all the its content(pdf's) stored in IBM filenet with docusign or any other tool which can let users to checkout the documents and add digital signatures and check in back.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be good if you explain a bit more about what you have researched so far, have you looked at docusign api, how you think integration would work. More details on checkout and checkin etc would help community to understand.

Comment: Ask about a specific issue you face.  "Any suggestions welcome" is far too broad and not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate issues here,

1. The ***content management***, which can typically be done using IBM FileNet, Microsoft SharePoint, Or Alfresco CMS.
2. The other issue is the ***digital signature***, which is validating and verifying the document source through a trust mechanism, which can be implemented using DocuSign, eSign Genie, or Adobe Document Cloud.

First you need to clearly address your solution intent, use cases, and features expected then you can have a direction to go.